# How to write a leap year algorithm in Javascript with TDD?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, tdd, jasmine-node, leap-year

I'm trying to write a leap year algorithm with a TDD suite. 
This is my first real attempt in working with TDD.

This is the code from the spec file.

```
var Year = require('./leap');

describe('Leap year', function() {

  it('is not very common', function() {
    var year = new Year(2015);
    expect(year.isLeap()).toBe(false);
  });

  it('is introduced every 4 years to adjust about a day', function() {
    var year = new Year(2016);
    expect(year.isLeap()).toBe(true);
  });

  it('is skipped every 100 years to remove an extra day', function() {
    var year = new Year(1900);
    expect(year.isLeap()).toBe(false);
  });

  it('is reintroduced every 400 years to adjust another day', function() {
    var year = new Year(2000);
    expect(year.isLeap()).toBe(true);
  });
```

This is the code so far from the leap.js file

```
var leapYear = function() {};

leapYear.prototype.isLeap = function(year) {
  if (year % 4 != 0) {
    return true;
  }
}

module.exports = leapYear;
```

I keep getting:

Failures:

1) Leap year is not very common
   Message:
     Expected true to be false.
   Stacktrace:
     Error: Expected true to be false.
    at null.

2) Leap year is skipped every 100 years to remove an extra day
   Message:
     Expected true to be false.
   Stacktrace:
     Error: Expected true to be false.
    at null.

Finished in 0.014 seconds
4 tests, 4 assertions, 2 failures, 0 skipped

Any ideas?

Comment: not returning anything in `else` condition

Comment: You've only accounted for one of 3 rules, consider `if (year % 4) /* not leap year*/`. Two to go. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be as simple as:

```
var leapYear = function(year) {this.year = year};

leapYear.prototype.isLeap = function() {
  return this.year % 4 == 0 && this.year % 100 != 0 || this.year % 400 == 0;
}

module.exports = leapYear;
```

If the year ends with 00 (in another word, `year % 100 == 0`), u should check if it can be divided by 400. Other wise just check if it can be divided by 4.

**Edit:**

Explanation:

*First the code*

- The test case wants a year object that constructs with a integer, hence your `leapYear` 'class' should take in a integer when constructing, and store it as a member variable.
- The isLeap function takes no argument, hence yours shouldn't take any argument as well, it uses the year it get when constructing this object.

*Then the math*

- 1st test case simply mean if a year can't be divided by 4, it is not a leap year.
- 2nd test case means if a year can be divided by 4, it is a leap year
- 3rd test case means if a year can be divided by 4, but ends with 00(every 100 year), it is not a leap year.
- 4th test case means if a year can be divided by 4, ends with 00, and can be divided by 400, it is a leap year.

Combining all these we know:

1. A year that cannot be divided by 4 is never a leap year.
2. A year that can be divided by 400 must be a leap year.
3. A year that can be divided by 4 is a leap year if it cannot be divided 100

so if you just test all these 3 case one by one, then u get your answer

Comment: Failures:

  1) Leap year is introduced every 4 years to adjust about a day
   Message:
     Expected false to be true.
   Stacktrace:
     Error: Expected false to be true.
    at null.<anonymous> 

  2) Leap year is reintroduced every 400 years to adjust another day
   Message:
     Expected false to be true.
   Stacktrace:
     Error: Expected false to be true.
    at null.<anonymous> 

Finished in 0.013 seconds
4 tests, 4 assertions, 2 failures, 0 skipped.

That's what I get when I tried your code.

Answer (score 0):

- `year % 4 != 0` in *non-leap* years (2013, 2014, 2015).
- You have no code yet to account for the 100-year and 400-year case.
- EDIT: As charlieftl says, `.toBe(false)` will not be satisfied.

Comment: There is no function like `isLeap` on `Date`, but internally, yes, it does. `new Date("1900/02/29").getDate()` says `1`, `new Date("2016/02/29").getDate()` says `29`.

Comment: just curious..have used it but never reaching out or back very far